# cant get maximum date in listing users php MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, and I want to get the last enterd date.

```
The first table is seeker:

seeker_nic-----username
111-------------ali
222-------------umer
333-------------raza

The second one is requestblood:

id-------seeker_nic-----requireddate
1-------  111 ----------2012/10/9
2 ------- 222-----------2012/5/8
3 ------  111-----------2012/12/12
4 ------- 111-----------2012/11/12
5---------111-----------2012/09/09
6 ------- 222-----------2012/7/9
7 ------- 333 ----------2012/4/4
```

Now, I want to list the users with their last inserted date like..

```
s.no---- username----- requireddate
 1------- ali---------- 2012/09/09
 2------- umer--------- 2012/7/9
 3------- raza--------- 2012/4/4
```

i am using this query

```
SELECT seeker.username,bloodrequest.requireddate, 
 max( bloodrequest.bloodrequest_id ) AS maxdate
FROM seeker
JOIN bloodrequest ON seeker.seeker_nic = bloodrequest.seeker_nic
GROUP BY seeker.username
```

when i run this query in phpmyadmin.. its lists all user and show the first inserted date of each user.. but i want the last inserted date  ... what should i do.. please i need help  :(

Comment: why are some dates `2012/5/8` and others `2012/09/09` ? Not consistent formatting.

Comment: these are dates that seeker inserted.. but i want show last inserted date when listing all users

Answer (score 0):

EDIT for real answer:

Not very clean sql, but it will get you the results you are looking for. I'm sure there's a way do it better with group by, but this works. :)

```
SELECT s.username,
(
    SELECT br1.requireddate 
    from bloodrequest as br1 
    where br1.bloodrequest_id = 
    (
        select max(br2.bloodrequest_id)
        from bloodrequest as br2 
        where br2.seeker_nic = s.seeker_nic
    )
) as requireddate
FROM seeker as s
```

Comment: requiresdate is stored as "date" but its still shows first date not the last inserted date :( @James

Comment: Didn't realize this when I looked at the code the first time, but you are taking the max of bloodrequest_id instead of requireddate.

Comment: i took max of bloodrequest_id so that i can show the date in  corresponding of max bloodrequest... i cant use max with requireddate.. because i want to show last inserted date not maximum date .. :( plz help mee @james

Comment: I edited my original answer with something that works. Tested it on my local with your exact table setup.

Comment: @james.. ur query works in phpmyadmin :)  but in my page i have some attributes that i have to show .. these are .......username, bloodgroup,area... how to adjust these attributes in your above query ??? :(

Comment: There's not enough information about your database in your request to tell you how to get bloodgroup,area, or anything else. But if bloodgroup is on your seeker table, your first line would become SELECT s.username, s.bloodgroup,

Comment: yes i got it... and it shows the result that i wanted... thank u soooo much.. i am really thankfull to you.. :) GOD BLESS YOU