# How to count total dates?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, and I want to get the last enterd date.

```
The first table is seeker:

seeker_nic-----username
111-------------ali
222-------------umer
333-------------raza

The second one is requestblood:

id-------seeker_nic-----requireddate
1-------  111 ----------2012/10/9
2 ------- 222-----------2012/5/8
3 ------  111-----------2012/12/12
4 ------- 111-----------2012/11/12
5---------111-----------2012/09/09
6 ------- 222-----------2012/7/9
7 ------- 333 ----------2012/4/4
```

i am listing user with last inserted date by this query

```
SELECT s.username,
(
    SELECT br1.requireddate 
    from bloodrequest as br1 
    where br1.bloodrequest_id = 
    (
        select max(br2.bloodrequest_id)
        from bloodrequest as br2 
        where br2.seeker_nic = s.seeker_nic
    )
) as requireddate
FROM seeker as s
```

this query works proper and show me data like this.

```
s.no---- username----- requireddate
 1------- ali---------- 2012/09/09
 2------- umer--------- 2012/7/9
 3------- raza--------- 2012/4/4
```

now i also want one more fild to show the total no of dates for a specific user .. like this

```
s.no---- username----- requireddate-----total dates
 1------- ali---------- 2012/09/09-------4
 2------- umer--------- 2012/7/9---------2
 3------- raza--------- 2012/4/4---------1
```

anyone please tell me how to adjust count in this query..
i shall be thankfull..... plzz need help

Comment: possible duplicate of [cant get maximum date in listing users php MYSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113465/cant-get-maximum-date-in-listing-users-php-mysql)

Comment: i was getting maximum date in that question,,, in this query i am getting last inserted date.. and want to count dates...difference in both questions.. plz helppp @deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the following work? Please give a try:

```
SELECT s.username,
(
    SELECT br1.requireddate
    from bloodrequest as br1 
    where br1.bloodrequest_id = 
    (
        select max(br2.bloodrequest_id)
        from bloodrequest as br2 
        where br2.seeker_nic = s.seeker_nic
    )
) as requireddate,
(
    SELECT count(br3.id)
    from bloodrequest as br3
        where br3.seeker_nic = s.seeker_nic
) as total_dates

FROM seeker as s
```

Though, it may not be the most efficient one.

Comment: @sarwar026... i got error "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: this is not worrking :( """#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from bloodrequest as br1 where br1.bloodrequest_id = ( select ' at line 4
"" got this error

Comment: sorry. i am deleting my answer

Comment: I am really sorry but bother you for one more time. can you please try once more please? If this is also not work, then i'll delete my answer.

Comment: i dont understand where is the problem.. i again git error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from bloodrequest as br1 where br1.bloodrequest_id = ( select ' at line 4
"   :(

Comment: Ohh sorry again. I have mistakenly put a comma(,) at line 4. Thats why the error possibly.

Comment: there was another **comma(,)** in as **total_dates,**. i am really sorry.

Comment: ohh that was another query i tried for count.. but when i combine queiry i again got errors :(